# Finding number of one to one functions given two sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The question reads:

Suppose the set $A$ has $m$ elements and the set $B$ has $n$ elements. There are $2^{mn}$ relations from $A$ to $B$ and $n^m$ functions from $A$ to $B$.

> $(a)$ If $m < n$, find the number of one-to-one functions from $A$ to $B$.
>
> $(b)$ If $m = n$, find the number of functions from $A$ onto $B$.

I'm not too sure where to even start to prove these. I understand if it's one to one that each $y$ in $B$ has only one $x$ in $A$. For the first one I feel like it has something to do with there being a limit on choice.

Comment: **Hint:** I added the tag *combinatorics* to your question.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the multiplication principle of counting?  Have you ever heard of permutations?  Can you see why part (a) is like asking "With $A=\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ and $B=\{a,b,\dots,n\}$, how many strings of length $m$ using letters from $B$ exist where letters aren't repeated?"

Comment: That would be like factorials right?

Comment: Factorials are indeed related to this problem.  Can you see how exactly?

Comment: Not too sure but it just looks like the choices go down since each x has only one y

Comment: @JMoravitz I am still unsure of how to continue with this problem

Comment: @Sam user138719's answer was already correct and complete, but I've gone ahead and added my own answer then since you still seemed confused.  Perhaps it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,m\}$ and let $B=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$

We count the number of one-to-one functions via [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

- Pick the value of $f(1)$:  There are $n$ available choices
- Pick the value of $f(2)$:  Since the function is meant to be one-to-one this must be different than the value of $f(1)$ so there are only $n-1$ remaining available choices
- Pick the value of $f(3)$:  This must be different than $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ so there are $n-2$ available choices
- $\vdots$
- Pick the value of $f(m)$:  This must be different than all of the $m-1$ preceding choices so there are $n-m+1$ choices available

Applying multiplication principle, there are then $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)$ functions from $A$ to $B$ which are one-to-one.

As an aside, the expression $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)$ is also able to be written as any of the following equivalent ways: as an [$m$-permutation of $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) as $P(n,m)$, as a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_factorial) as $n\frac{m}{~}$ or $(n)_m$, using binomial coefficients as $\binom{n}{m}m!$ (*this is how @user138719 wrote his answer*) or even as a ratio of factorials as $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$.

In the special case that $n=m$ the one-to-one functions from $A$ to $B$ are referred to as permutations and all of the above expressions for the number of such functions simplifies to an answer of $n!$.

Note, the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ is often denoted as $B^A$ and is of cardinality $|B|^{|A|}$.  Similarly, the set of one-to-one functions from $A$ to $B$ is sometimes denoted as $B\frac{A}{~}$ and is of cardinality $|B|\frac{|A|}{~}$.

Comment: Okay this makes more sense to me. I just don't understand the m=n case as to how it's permutation but then only factorial n is the answer. Does this use part a?

Comment: @Sam a permutation is *by definition* a bijective function from a set to itself.  One can easily show that a one-to-one function from a set with $n$ elements to another set with $n$ elements must also be bijective.  The number of permutations on an $n$ element set is $n!$.  Infact, $n\frac{n}{~}=n!$ so the answers agree.

Comment: Then if I wanted to show this would it be the case that if we pick 1 u have n choices if we pick 2 we have n-1 choices and when we get to the point to pick m we will only have one choice since n=m each values has a choice

Comment: How does n-m+1 get to n-m only

Comment: @sam if referring to ratio of factorial, notice we want to keep all terms (n-m+1) and larger and we want to cancel all terms (n-m) and smaller

Comment: Yes I am referring to the ratio. I am not sure how it got to that point where the 1 is erased.

Comment: @Sam worded another way, we begin with $\underbrace{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)}_{m~\text{terms}}$.  By multiplying and dividing by $(n-m)!$ (*which won't change the VALUE at all, just how it looks*) we have now $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)\cdot (n-m)!}{(n-m)!}$ and we can now reinterpret the top as a factorial, noting the property that $(k+1)\cdot k!=(k+1)!$ and using that $m$ times.  Thus $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$

Comment: THen this was just a form to change it to be a more general form?

Comment: @Sam yes, like I said all of these answers are equal and equally valid: $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}=n\frac{m}{~}=P(n,m)=\dots$  Choose whichever one you prefer

Comment: Okay I understand the first since I have yet to learn cardinality.

Comment: Also for the m=n case wouldn't it be m! instead?

Comment: @Sam in the case that $n=m$ you have $n!=m!=P(n,n)=P(m,m)=P(n,m)=P(m,n)=\frac{n!}{0!}=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}=\dots$ so yes it is $m!$ and it is also anything else I've written...

Comment: Just back to the (k+1)! This is what you apply to the n variable?

Comment: I actually meant to say for the m=n case to find number of functions A onto B. Or Surjection.

Comment: @Sam This will be my final response.  If you have future questions for clarification, start a new question.  There should not be so many comments.  As for the case for $m=n$ you should already know or be able to prove that every function from $A$ to $B$ is one to one if and only if it is also onto.  All onto functions from an $n$ element set to an $n$ element set is also one to one and vice versa.  As a result, your attempt to clarify or change your question does not at all change the answer, there are still $n!$ such functions.

Comment: @Sam if you were to change the question for the first part as well, there exist no onto functions from $A$ to $B$ when $|A|<|B|$ and in the case that $|A|>|B|$ you will need to read about stirling numbers of the second kind which are not usually introduced until a graduate course in combinatorics and so are probably outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Okay, sorry for such a long comment but i realized far too late that my question was not worded correctly and I just panicked.  for the m=n case I just did n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)....(1)=n!=m!. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my answer.

If $m = n$, then a one-to-one function would also have to be onto (since being one-to-one means that you can't have a repeated output, then each input must go to a different output, and there are $m$ inputs and $n = m$ outputs).

So, this is just like asking: "How many ways can you rearrange $m$ different numbers?"
The answer is actually a way to define something called the factorial function, which is:

$$m! = m(m-1)(m-2)...(2)(1)$$

If $m < n$, then we must first choose which $m$ of the $n$ values will be the outputs of the function. This is also a known function, refered to as a *binomial coefficient* (lots to read on this), and which I will write as:

$$NChooseM = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$
This calculates how many different ways we can choose an unordered set of $m$ objects from a group of $n$ objects.

Now, for *each* of these different ways, we are looking back at question (a) above. Since there were $m!$ different one-to-one functions from a set of size $m$ to another set of size $m$, we now have

$$NChooseM*m! = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}*m! = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$$
different one-to-one functions from a set of size $m$ to a set of size $n$, when $m < n$.

Notice that the above formula reduces to that from question (a) when $n = m$ (because $0! = 1$).

For a visual, I also like the table of values approach:

Draw a rectangular grid which has $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Here, a row corresponds to an input value, and a column corresponds to an output value.
If you draw an $X$ in the box which is in row $p$ and column $q$, this corresponds to the statement $f(p) = q$ for the function.

In part (a), where $m = n$, this is just a square grid. For a one-to-one function, each column (output) may have only one $X$ in it, and since $f$ is a function, each row may only have one $X$ in it.

Going down each row, you may only choose one column for there to be an $X$. So, beginning with the first row, you have $n$ choices for where the X goes. Once that is done, you have only $n-1$ choices for where the $X$ goes in the second row. By the multiplication principle, you would multiply your number of choices for each row, giving you 
$$n(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1) = n!$$

different functions of this type.

In part (b), where $m < n$, you must first reduce the number of columns so that $m = n$. That is, you must choose which columns will be the range of the function. This would, again, be using the $NChooseM$ formula, and then multiplying that number of possible choices by the result in part (a).

Comment: This is all well and good, though a bit long winded.  For notation/typesetting, binomial coefficients are usually written `\binom{n}{m}` displaying as $\binom{n}{m}$.  For the case when $m<n$, the notation of [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_factorial) is more compact as $n\frac{m}{~}$ or $(n)_m$ or also common $P(n,m)$.